# Error al mostrar resultado

Tags: python

> Desarrolle una aplicación que permita ingresar la cantidad de trabajadores necesarios
>   para una obra urbana. Además, debe pedir el sueldo que esos trabajadores percibirán.
>   Una vez ingresados esos datos, mostrar el costo total en dicho concepto. Después
>   pedir un porcentaje de descuento (decimal). Aplique dicho descuento al monto
>   mostrado anteriormente y muestre el monto final de la construcción.

Tengo el siguiente problema para resolver, pero mi gran duda que al ingresar los datos y luego multiplicar por el sueldo:

```
sueldo_total = (sueldo * num_trabajadores,)
```

Pero me arroja un error:

> sueldo_total = (sueldo * num_trabajadores,)
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

¿Qué podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es asegurarte de alguna manera que __unicamente__ tienes valores numéricos en las variables. Por ejemplo, `3000` es un número, pero `3,000` no lo es. Edita tu pregunta para agregar el código relevante de tu problema. Sigue esta guía __[mcve]__.

Comment: Como te comenta toledano deberias editar la pregunta y aportar el código que estás intentando para poder ver donde está el error. Posiblemente estas usando `input` en python 3 o `raw_input` en python 2 para ingresar los datos sin tener en cuenta que retornan una cadena y no puedes multiplicar dos cadenas, debes cambiar el tipo a`float` o `int` .

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando esa parte del código por esto:

```
sueldo_total = (int(sueldo) * int(num_trabajadores))
```

así podras multiplicarlos ya que si utilizaste raw_input para introducir tanto el sueldo como el numero de trabajadores, estos serán strings y no puedes multiplicar strings.

Answer (score 1):

El error simplemente indica que estas intentando multiplicar dos datos de tipo `str` (cadenas de texto). Tus datos `sueldo` y `num_trabajadores` deben ser enteros (`int`) o decimales (`float`) si el sueldo no es un numero entero.

Simplemente debes hacer el casting adecuadamente:

```
sueldo_total = float(sueldo) * int(num_trabajadores)
```

Lo que seguramente pasa es que estas tomando los datos mediante entradas desde consola. Como te mostré en un comentario a tu pregunta, tanto `raw_input` en Python 2.x como `input` en Python 3.x retornan una cadena (`str`). Puedes hacer el casting en la misma linea del `input`/`raw_input`:

```
sueldo = float(input('Ingrese el sueldo por trabajador: '))
num_trabajadores= int(input('Ingrese el numero de trabajadores: '))
sueldo_total = sueldo * num_trabajadores
```